# Create Array Formula from Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Could anybody help me to solve my problem?
I have two sheet spreadsheet sheet 1 from quiz response and sheet 2 is the result I want.
I have difficulty to create an array formula in sheet 2 based data from quiz response.
I need an array result with green color.
Below is the picture.
[image: sheet from response]
[image: sheet I want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
=arrayformula(trim(split(flatten(query(query({B:B&char(9999),C:C&char(9999)},"select Max(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2",1),"",9^9)),char(9999))))
```

[image]